# Do extension tubes work well with the AFS VR micro nikkor 105mm f/2.8G?

Tags: nikon, extension-tubes, macro-lenses

Has  anyone who owns the Micro Nikkor 105mm f/2.8 G used extensions tubes with it? How does the lens perform in this case? I'm interested in getting magnification beyond 1:1. Will this help, and are there any issues I should be aware of?

Comment: Is the question "Can extension tubes take this lens beyond 1:1?" or is it "Do different brands of extension tubes work?" or is it something else?

Comment: 1. They aren't useless, you just have to know the limitations of them. This is no different then any other equipment, it isn't perfect. 2. "Great difficulty" shouldn't be part of the equation when you can just go pick up a $10 set of Fotodiox extension tubes on Amazon and try it. 3. Nothing on the 'net will ever equal in person trials and error.

Answer (score 1):

I've used close-up filters on mine, which are basically just magnifying lenses that you can attach to the front. It works, fully stacked I get about 2.5:1 magnification, but you really have to work to recover the sharpness I found.

Nevertheless, as the 105mm can be used with a Nikon teleconverter (no autofocus), that basically means that it will work fine with any extension tube that I'm aware of. Kenko makes a reasonable option that I've seen recommended before. If you're really nervous about it, take your gear into the camera store or have them show you with their display models.

Comment: Thanks, I have a four lense set of those screw on magnifiers and you are correct about sharpness.